# XSL test if current attribute is the same as previous attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble with getting the previous attribute to use that in my test case.

This is how the end result should be.

```
<rows>
   <row id="1">
      <cell>Advances RTF - Regul ILIAS</cell>
   </row>
   <row id="2">
      <cell style="color: RED">Advances RTF - Regul ILIAS</cell>
   </row>
   <row id="3">
      <cell style="color: GREEN">Advances RTF - Regul ILIAS</cell>    
   </row>    
   </row>
   <row id="4">
      <cell>Analysis of the consumption of paymaster's advances</cell>      
   </row>
   <row id="5">
      <cell style="color: GREEN">Analysis of the consumption of paymaster's advances</cell>      
   </row>
   <row id="6">
      <cell>Analytic Image</cell>      
   </row>
   <row id="7">
      <cell style="color: GREEN">Analytic Image</cell>    
   </row>
   <row id="8">
      <cell>Analytic Image - System</cell>  
   </row>
   <row id="9">
      <cell style="color: GREEN">Analytic Image - System</cell>
   </row>
</rows>
```

I'm starting with a XML file that looks like this. I removed a lot of extra attributes because it was not relevant to show here.

```
-<dbqueries>
-<dbquery id="algemeen_overview_1_lijn">
    -<rows>
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Advances RTF - Regul ILIAS" />
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Advances RTF - Regul ILIAS" />
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Advances RTF - Regul ILIAS" />
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Analysis of the consumption of paymaster's advances" />
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Analysis of the consumption of paymaster's advances" />
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Analytic Image" />
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Analytic Image" />
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Analytic Image - System" />
        <row LRF_DESCRIPTION="Analytic Image - System" />
    </rows>
</dbquery>
```

To get the result I want I'm using an xls file.

```
    <xsl:template match="/">    
    <rows>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//dbquery[@id='algemeen_overview_1_lijn']/rows/row"/>
    </rows>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//dbquery[@id='algemeen_overview_1_lijn']/rows/row">
    <xsl:element name="row">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>                    
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current()/@LRF_DESCRIPTION != preceding-sibling::row[@LRF_DESCRIPTION]">
                    <cell>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@LRF_DESCRIPTION"/>
                    </cell>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
                            <cell style="color: #EBF3FF;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@LRF_DESCRIPTION"/>
                            </cell>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <cell style="color: #FFFFFF;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@LRF_DESCRIPTION"/>
                            </cell>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

So what this Choose part should do is the following.
If LRF_DESCRIPTION != previous lrf_description 
then show the LRF_description with no style color.

If LRF_DESCRIPTION = previous lrf_description
then check if this is an even or odd position (row number)
  if it's even, show the LRF_description in RED color
  if it's uneven, show the LRF_description in GREEN color.

The part to check even or odd workt fine. The problem is that I cannot get the first part working.

Anyway thx for your time reading this.

Comment: This looks like a *grouping* question. Can you use XSLT  2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close to the solution. The following line fixed the attribute handling of `LRF_DESCRIPTION` and added an exception for the first item.
Change the first `<xsl:when test="..."` condition to

```
current()/@LRF_DESCRIPTION != preceding-sibling::row[1]/@LRF_DESCRIPTION or count(preceding-sibling::row) = 0
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. The Or solution got rid of the problem that I lost the first row. Wanted to click "Answer is usefull" but I got to low rep.
Just one question, the row[1] does that mean previous 1 row? The reason for that question is, that I first tried with row[position() - 1] but that didn't work.

Comment: `row[1]` means "first of a sequence of rows", so `preceding-sibling::row[1]` means "first of the sequence of preceding-row-siblings".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<xsl:when test="current()/@LRF_DESCRIPTION != preceding-sibling::row[@LRF_DESCRIPTION]">` to `<xsl:when test="@LRF_DESCRIPTION != preceding-sibling::row[1]/@LRF_DESCRIPTION">` to make sense in terms of the XML structure and the attribute comparison.

Comment: This is indeed a very good solution. Only lost the very first row. The solution @zx485 gave solved that problem also.